# Raycast not working in start method but working in fixupdate methods with same code

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

## Background

I want to raycast one random position cube call start to another random position cube called end, to see if the ray hit a cylinder. it only needs to compute once when every time the game started.

## What I have done

So I put the code in the start which looks like this:

```
void Start()
    {
        GameObject start = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        GameObject end = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        start.transform.position = new Vector3(20, 20, 12);
        end.transform.position = new Vector3(-20, 20 , 10);

        GameObject safeZone = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);
        safeZone.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        safeZone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(40, 40 ,40);

        bool ifCross = Physics.Raycast(start.transform.position,
            (end.transform.position - start.transform.position),
            out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity);
        if (ifCross)
        {
            Debug.Log("success");
            Debug.DrawRay(start.transform.position,
                (end.transform.position - start.transform.position),
                Color.green, 100f);
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("fail");
            Debug.DrawRay(start.transform.position,
                (end.transform.position - start.transform.position),
                Color.red, 100f);
        }


    }
```

This code always return fails， but in the scene, the debug ray is hitting the cylinder.

## What I have tried:

- Move the ifCross related code to update, it works properly and returns the excepted result.
- Instead of creating the cube in start, if I make the cubes object public, and draw the cubes in unity editor, it works fine. (only works when the position is set in unity editor, but it is not what I want because I need random position for cubes.

## Question

Why raycast is working in update but not in start?
Why pre-set cubes can work in start?
How to make random cubes position in start and make raycast working?

Any reference is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the order of execution for the script lifecycle in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), you will see that Start executes before FixedUpdate.

Since FixedUpdate is where the physics system performs its collision calculations, the Physics.Raycast call in your Start method will not know where colliders are/will be and thus won't be able to determine whether the ray has intersected a collider.

You may be able to find a workable solution using [Physics.Simulate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Simulate.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  The order of the execution graph makes a lot of sense. but why raycast can detect the collider if I drag the cube from the editor and set the position in the editor?  the code is still in start method.

Comment: Because in this case the physics is once pre-simulated for the already existing objects when entering PlayMode. If you spawn or move an object during `Start` the physics is not yet recalculated. As mentioned in the answer you can force that via `Physics.Simulate`

Comment: thank you HumanWrites and derHugo. it completely solved my doubts.